# Relationship involving Lebesgue integral of supremum of function depending on a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous and nonnegative. For each $x\in\mathbb{R}$ define $f_x:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ by
$$f_x(y)=f(x,y)\qquad(y\in\mathbb{R}).$$
Is there a Fatou's-Lemma-like relationship between
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}f_x(y)\,dy$$
and
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_x(y)\,dy?$$
If so, what would it be, exactly, and how would it be proven. If some other conditions are needed for such a relationship, please feel free to suggest them. What's not alterable is that $x$ can take on uncountably many values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any $x$ we have $f_x(y) \le \sup_{x' \in \mathbb{R}} f_{x'}(y)$ for all $y$, so
$$\int f_x(y) \, dy \le \int \sup_{x' \in \mathbb{R}} f_{x'}(y) \, dy$$
holds for any $x$. Then take the supremum with respect to $x$ on the left-hand side.

Comment: Thank you! That was quite easy. I should have seen that myself.